# Drupal 6, Locale Module & Language Fallbacks

Tags: nodes, 6, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 6 website, with 4 different locales, but only 2 different languages.

The 4 locales are setup as follows:

en, site.com, (American English)

en-ca, site.ca, (Canadian English)

fr, site.com/fr, (European French)

fr-ca, site.com/fr-ca, (Canadian French)

The language negotiation is set to "Path prefix only".

Content selection mode is set to "Current language and language neutral".

American english is the default locale.

As the language negotiation is set to "Path prefix only" site.ca falls back to American English as expected.

However, all the French content is entered in the European French locale. Leaving the Canadian French site empty, and broken.

Is there a way (in Drupal 6) to either:

a) select multipul languages per node.
b) set a fallback languages.

I see that in Drupal 7 you have the ability to select multipul languages for a single node. There are also many modules available for Drupal 7 to enable language fallbacks.

I tried implementing a quick hack:

```
function hook_theme_init() {
  global $language;
  if($language->language == 'fr-ca') {
    $language->language = 'fr';
  }
}
```

This almost works as it starts pulling all the European French content, Node Queue and the language switcher don't seem to like this hack.

Aside from cloning all the the French European content into the French Canadian Locale, is there any way of accomplishing language fallbacks?

Comment: did u add custom language?

Comment: Yes, I am using custom languages.

Comment: I'm going to need the same thing with my D6 site (fr-CA, fr-FR, pt-BR, pt-PT). Guessing I'll run into the same issue with node translations. Did you come up with a workable solution?